# What is TombstonedTaskError from App Engine's Task Queue?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

What does the `TombstonedTaskError` mean? It is being raised while trying to add a task to the queue, from a cron-job:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/webapp/__init__.py", line 501, in __call__
    handler.get(*groups)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/.../tasks.py", line 132, in get
    ).add(queue_name = 'userfeedcheck')
  File "/base/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/labs/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 495, in add
    return Queue(queue_name).add(self)
  File "/base/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/labs/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 563, in add
    self.__TranslateError(e)
  File "/base/python_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/labs/taskqueue/taskqueue.py", line 619, in __TranslateError
    raise TombstonedTaskError(error.error_detail)
TombstonedTaskError
```

Searching the documentation only has the following to say:

> ```
> exception TombstonedTaskError(InvalidTaskError)
>     Task has been tombstoned.
> ```

..which isn't particularly helpful.

I couldn't find anything useful in the [App Engine code](http://code.google.com/p/soc/source/browse/thirdparty/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/labs/taskqueue/) either..

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You've added a task with that exact name before. Although it's already run, executed task names are kept around for some time to prevent accidental duplicates. If you're assigning task names, you should be using ones that are globally unique to prevent this occurring.

Comment: Why they are preventing from adding tasks with the same name AFTER the old task has finished?
If it is that way, they should allow a way to check what tasks are in the queue.

Comment: @krzyk Because otherwise there'd be a race condition where you add a task with that name just as it finishes. The point of task names is to prevent repeat execution.

Comment: How long is "some time"? minutes? hours? days?

Comment: @jgeewax 7 days, as a rule. That's not something you should be relying on, though.

Comment: TaskAlreadyExistsError also seems to be raised sometimes. What is the difference between the two exceptions?

Comment: @ema TaskAlreadyExistsError is thrown when a task is currently in the queue with that name. TombstonedTaskError is thrown when the name was used for a previously executed task.