# Can an app engine taskqueue task be rescheduled?

Tags: google-app-engine, task-queue

During an API call, I schedule a task to be executed n minutes later. I name the task.

Another API call, if executed, will delete the task.

When the task is executed (where all datastore operations are performed in a transaction), it also checks if it needs to wait some more. If so, I would like to complete the task successfully, but also submit a task (to be executed n minutes later) with the same name, so it can still be cancelled by the previously mentioned API call.

I do not see anything in the documentation about a task adding a new task with the same name before completing successfully, or about a task deleting itself and submitting a new task with the same name (especially within a transaction).

(Even if I got it to work, I want to make sure it was due to supported functionality. The system handles real payments.)

Thank you for your input. /Alexander

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware you can't re-use task names for quite some time.

There is no currently defined tombstone time for tasks,

See [For how long are task names tombstoned in AppEngine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728828/for-how-long-are-task-names-tombstoned-in-appengine)

See also [What is TombstonedTaskError from App Engine's Task Queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101162/what-is-tombstonedtaskerror-from-app-engines-task-queue) which suggests names are held for up to 7 days.

I think you need to find an alternate method for whatever you are trying to do or elaborate on your use case and maybe there is a better/alternate approach.

Answer (score 1):

When i have tested use named tasks, i couldn't in a short time create a new task whit the same name, neither in some minutes..., I think you can use a mixture of a cron whit variables stored in a datastore entity, the cron to review each some time the status variables in the datastore and to launch any task if is needed.